# Does a Dafny assert statement have power?

Tags: dafny

My understanding from reading the literature is that assert statements are only for the user to be able to see what the verifier thinks a certain point. However in my own experience I have seen that in the case of lemmas, an assert statement actually *changes* what the verifier thinks and allows a lemma to be proved.

Can anyone clarify?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding assert statements can help Dafny prove lemmas, and this is typically how a programmer guides Dafny's proof search. In particular, Dafny might be able to prove a given intermediate statement, and it might be able to use that statement to prove a desired lemma, but it wouldn't know to look for that statement without the programmer providing it.

Experience with Dafny helps build intuition about what kind of assertions are helpful to Dafny. (I suggest reading about [triggers](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#how-does-dafny-handle-quantifiers-ive-heard-about-triggers-what-are-those), which will illuminate how Dafny proof search works. Triggers are patterns that Dafny uses as hints to know when to instantiate a quantified variable; the art of using assertions to guide Dafny is often about finding the right triggers.)